# Authorization with jersey client

Tags: java, rest, curl, jersey, go-cd

I am trying to convert this curl command into a jersey request:

`curl host:8154/go/api/pipelines/build_service/schedule -u 'username:password'`

I am almost there but I keep getting 401 Unauthorized. Here is my client

```
this.client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(userAuth(username, password))
                .withConfig(config)
                .hostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHostNameVerifier())
                .sslContext(new Ssl().getSslContext())
                .build();
```

And here is the userAuth

```
private HttpAuthenticationFeature userAuth(String username, String password) {
    return HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, password);
}
```

Doesn't `-u` option mean basic authorization?

Comment: It's not really the `-u` option which indicates a basic auth. However, since no other authentication methods are provided, `--basic` is assumed. Thus, your curl command uses indeed basic authentication. See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--basic.

Comment: If that is the case, then why does my request call fail to authorize my username and password to the server?

Comment: Try adding `-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v1+json'`, which you need to use the API. Not sure if you're supposed to get an "unauthorized" error for that though.

Comment: I have a working curl command, but the problem is my request doesnt work given basic authroization

Comment: Are you running the server? If so, is there anything in the server logs that may indicate something wrong? Also is there any message in the response body? You might want to do some logging on both the server any client by registering the LoggingFilter/Feature.

Comment: I dont think it is on the server side. I think it is the way jersey handles the authorization. I have a httpsurlconnection from the java.net library executing rest call just fine, but I would eventually like to have a jersey client up and running.